# AWS Polly with PHP save .mp3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I need a script to take my text, convert it to speech using AWS Polly API and save it on my server as mp3 file.

Currently when I load a page a player appears and plays back the speech clip but no file is downloaded.

What am I missing?

```
require '../../../include/lib/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

// Creating Amazon Polly Client

use Aws\Polly\PollyClient;

$config = [
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-west-2', //region
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'MY_KEY',
        'secret' => 'my_AWS_secret',
    ]];

$client = new PollyClient($config);

// Converting Text to Speech via Polly API

$args = [
    'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
    'Text' => "<speak><prosody rate='medium'>My text goes here..</prosody></speak>",
    'TextType' => 'ssml',
    'VoiceId' => "Joanna",
];

$result = $client->synthesizeSpeech($args);

$resultData = $result->get('AudioStream')->getContents();

// Listening the text
$size   = strlen($resultData); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:chunked');
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: $length");
echo $resultData;


// Download the Text to Speech in MP3 Format

header('Content-length: ' . strlen($resultData));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="./myfile.mp3"');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
echo $resultData;
```

Comment: if you switch the order of the "Listening the text" and "Download the Text to Speech in MP3 Format" sections of code it will download but not play? (if so, you need to make 2 separate requests, you cant sent 2 responses to a single request like this)

Comment: Wow, swapping the two actually did the trick. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sending 2 responses one after the other. The first will be processed the second most likely will be ignored.

Basically you cant send headers after you already sent content. Refactor your code so you only send 1 response per request.

Answer (score 1):

simply save the output in a new file:

```
file_put_contents("output.mp3", $resultData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ file_put_contents("output.mp3", $resultData);
```

This command worked for me as I was able to download the file on my local desktop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).